# How to upload image from front end and save in media library?

Tags: attachments, uploads

I am working on a plugin .I want to upload image from front end i.e by `input type="file"`.I did lot of google for it but could not upload image .Here is my code for uploading image

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
  <input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload"   multiple="false" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="55" />
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
  <input id="submit_my_image_upload" name="submit_my_image_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>

<?php

if ( 
    isset( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], $_POST['post_id'] ) 
    && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_image_upload_nonce'], 'my_image_upload' )
    && current_user_can( 'edit_post', $_POST['post_id'] )
) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_image_upload', $_POST['post_id'] );

    if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
        // There was an error uploading the image.
    } else {
        // The image was uploaded successfully!
    }

} else {

    // The security check failed, maybe show the user an error.
}
function wp_verify_nonce_X($nonce, $action = -1) {
        return true;
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $uid = (int) $user->id;
        $i = wp_nonce_tick();
        if ( substr(wp_hash($i . $action . $uid, 'nonce'), -12, 10) == $nonce )
            return 1;
        if ( substr(wp_hash(($i - 1) . $action . $uid, 'nonce'), -12, 10) == $nonce )
            return 2;
        // Invalid nonce
        return false;
    }
After implementing this code  I get thiserror 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_verify_nonce() in /home/projectdemos/public_html/WP-Team-Showcase/wp-content/plugins/wp-team-showcase/team.php on line 435
```

I google this error and run all possible solution found across it but could not solved it .
Tell me how to upload image and save it ,if there is any other solution beside my this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I have an answer for my own question.I solved this issue by using this code.I add this code just for sharing and helping  other as it works for me.

```
<input type="file" name="my_file_upload" id="my_file_upload_id" class="bg_checkbox"  >

function register_team_show_case_setting() {
//register our settings
    register_setting('my_team_show_case_setting', 'my_file_upload');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'register_team_show_case_setting');
```

Code to upload and save image:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$attach_id = media_handle_upload('my_file_upload', $post_id);
if (is_numeric($attach_id)) {
    update_option('option_image', $attach_id);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id);
}
```

Display image code

```
echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_option('option_image'));
```

Comment: Hello. How can i upload multiple images with your example?

Answer (score 0):

You call for a WordPress function before WordPress is fully loaded.
A quick and dirty way to fix this is to add

```
require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```

at the top of your plugin file so it has the needed functions.

A better and the correct way of solving this is to wait with your code until WordPress is done by using one of the available hooks

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_228301' );
```

or

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_228301' );
```

Comment: after using `require_once(ABSPATH .'wp-includes/pluggable.php');` at the top  error removed but no imageis uploading to media library

Comment: I urge you to develop the plugin as it should be, so use the __init__ or __wp_loaded__ action hooks to initialize the plugin. That way all wordpress functions are available to you.
The way you are handling it now with requiring files works in most cases but is definitely not how it should be done. Also I aimed to get rid of your error message, I did not check your entire code so if the error you had is gone, some other part of your code is not working properly.

Comment: I have uploaded image using this code `<input type="file" name="my_file_upload" id="my_file_upload"><?php
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$attach_id = media_handle_upload( 'my_file_upload', $post_id );
if ( is_numeric( $attach_id ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_file_upload', $attach_id );
}
?>` In my `team.php` file .Now I want to display it in `post-type.php` file Can you tell me how to display it ?

Comment: You should make a new post for this to avoid cluttering since this issue is resolved but you save it as post meta "_my_file_upload" so you can get it back on the front-end by retreiving that post meta:

`$attachment = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_file_upload' );`

Comment: `$attachment = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_my_file_upload' );` it gives me a empty array

Comment: This is not gonna work in comments. Please open a new topic for this :)

Comment: I have paste my code hee plz checked it `http://pastebin.com/mXNC2UMJ`

Comment: One more time, please provide a new topic with sufficient information so that me and other people can have a proper post to work with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40645/discussion-between-raxa-and-jeffrey-von-grumbkow).