# Wordpress Media Uploader in page template (On Front-end)

Tags: theme-development, images, uploads, media, front-end

I've tried to use Media Uploader in a page template, so registered users can upload some images, but I'm not sure is it possible. I know I need to include some scripts and I've called `wp_enqueue_media();` in functions.php, and when call it I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at shortcode.min.js?ver=4.8.1:1
    at shortcode.min.js?ver=4.8.1:1
```

Also, I have this code to open Media Uploader on click

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var custom_uploader;

    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
        if (custom_uploader) {
            custom_uploader.open();
            return;
        }

        //Extend the wp.media object
        custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose Image',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Image'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

        //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
        custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
            attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            $('#upload_image').val(attachment.url);
        });

        //Open the uploader dialog
        custom_uploader.open();

    });


});
```

This is how I call it in functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'media_uploader_script');
function media_uploader_script() {
    if (is_page_template('user-page-template.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find you answer : [how-to-upload-image-from-front-end-and-save-in-media-library](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/228301/how-to-upload-image-from-front-end-and-save-in-media-library)